# Rails API vis iOS

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, api, devise, afnetworking

I have a rails app that requires a user to login with devise. Once logged in, the user can create a location and add a menu. I want to access the api via an iOS app using AFnetworking, but when authenticating the iOS app, I want to have access to the entire API not just one locations data.

Example: User opens ios app, clicks on locations, selects a location, selects beer menu, displays a list of beers from the api.

How can I do this when authentication on the rails side gives access to one locations results?

I want the iOS user to have access to the entire api, which I view in rails console as Location.all and Beer.all

The output I get in xcode when calling the beers.json endpoint

```
2013-02-22 09:44:25.834 BeerList[23137:c07] Error fetching beers!
2013-02-22 09:44:25.835 BeerList[23137:c07] Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code <NSIndexSet: 0x6a3ee70>[number of indexes: 100 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (200-299)], got 500" UserInfo=0xbe29090 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:3000/beers.json, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code <NSIndexSet: 0x6a3ee70>[number of indexes: 100 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (200-299)], got 500}
```

I assume this is because the iOS app is not authenticated. If I were to pass a username and password, I assume it would give me data for that user's location, but not all locations. Is there a way to authenticate the iOS app so that it can retrieve all locations data?

Comment: please be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a super user that has no location. Implement a mechanism in your rails app that allows all locations to be retrieved for that user. The iOS app can simply log in as the super user.

As you did not share any code, that is all that we can tell you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot and ask a more specific question with code when I get a little further.

Comment: Good we could clarify that. Please accept the answer and open a new question once you have pinpointed the problem.